# Icon not showing in React.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, icons, react-native-elements

Icons not showing in React Native JS.
I check all of the codes but I can't find any problem.
When I run it in Android, the Icon not showing

```
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Icon} from 'react-native-elements';

const ContactListScreen = (props) => {
 return (
 <View style={styles.buttonView}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.addButton}>
          <Icon name="plus" type="antdesign" size={24} color="black" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
 </View>
 );
};

export default ContactListScreen;
```

Comment: Does it work when running not on Android? I think you have to put the JSX in the return-statement of a functional component or in the render-method of a class-component.

Comment: @kzi Unfortunately I can only run it on Android, so I don't know the results if it's run on other than Android. Also, thanks for the suggestion, I actually put the return statement but I forgot to put the return statement code in my question, my bad :)

Answer (score 0):

for icons react-native-elements depend on a library [react-native-vector-icons](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vector-icons)

you have to follow the installation guide for react native vector icons mentioned in the documentation